# Searching inside a JSON object in Google Chrome DevTools

Tags: json, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I love Google Chrome's DevTools. But, when debugging I sometimes need to search for a particular property or value in a JSON request/response object (within a request/response in the "Network" tab). This can be tedious if the JSON object is large. Do the DevTools support such a search?

In the example below, I was hoping that searching for "new_user" would highlight the property in the JSON object shown.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**: Since this question was asked, this functionality has been added to Chrome!

Comment: Then how to do it if it has been added? Please add the correct answer :)

Comment: @Lee so how u do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No existing functionality to search the json tree view. You can file a new issue in the [issue tracker](http://crbug.com/new) to see if it could get added.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. Have you received requests for such a feature before? Will it be worthwhile to file such a ticket or will it gather dust?

Comment: Thanks for asking if we received it before, just checked and [sure enough we have one](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402656). So go star that issue to let the team know you want it done. Also comment with a link to your question so the team can see another use-case for the feature.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt attention. Will do and happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

The feature seem to be now implemented:

1. Click on the XHR request you want to see.
2. Click on the "Preview" or "Response" tab and do CTRL + F

Comment: I want to search across all XHR Responses

Comment: Ditto.   I'm debugging a site that has hundreds of requests and I want to find the one I need by search for data inside the requests

Answer (score 0):

Workaround in Chrome (Really wish this was natively available):

1. Filter by Fetch/XHR
2. Select all
3. Save all as HAR with content
4. Open the file with your favorite text editor
5. Search